# Failed to generate preview for user - with common action type

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Could someone help me with that? I made a custom story and it works perfectly I just can't figure out what's wrong with this common action type. Window is just opening and closing second after with an exception.

```
public void publishCommonOpenGraphStory() {

    OpenGraphObject book = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("book");
    book.setProperty("title", "Harry Potter");
    book.setProperty("description", "Description of HP book.");
    book.setProperty("url", "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Harry-Potter-6/115538755123952?rf=376474059116356");
    book.setProperty("image", "<img_url>"); // url was long so I cut it there

    OpenGraphAction ogAction = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    ogAction.setProperty("book", book);
    ogAction.setType("books.reads");

    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, ogAction, "book")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Thing is I get an error:

```
07-25 14:44:19.671  31907-31907/com.example.facebooktest E/ActivityResult.onComplete﹕ Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to generate preview for user.
```

I do not know where the problem is, for me everything seems alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong with that method.
When using common facebook object (like books.book in this example) you have to check which fields are essential (not null) for each object. 
I had to add book isbn number as property, which must be filled:

```
book.getData().setProperty("isbn", "2-07-057267-6");
```

This can be find in facebook developers site in docs. 
Example: 
[books.book doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/books.book)

Whole method code looks like this now:

```
public void publishCommonOpenGraphStory() {
    OpenGraphObject book = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("books.book");
    book.setProperty("title", "Harry Potter");
    book.setProperty("description", "Description of HP book.");
    book.setProperty("url", "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Harry-Potter-6/115538755123952?rf=376474059116356");
    book.setProperty("image", "<img link>");
    book.getData().setProperty("isbn", "2-07-057267-6");


    OpenGraphAction ogAction = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    ogAction.setProperty("book", book);
    ogAction.setType("books.reads");

    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, ogAction, "book")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
}
```

Comment: Does this code still works? I've tried this as is and my app goes into some kind of infinite loop trying to open the Facebook App (shows white screen - shows facebook's splash - white screen...), but if I remove this line "book.setProperty("image", "<img link>");" the dialog shows and after a few seconds it closes throwing the same exception: "Failed to generate preview for user". Did you modify something else?

Comment: Ok, now sometimes it just goes into the loop and sometimes it just freezes at the Facebook's splash screen throwing StackOverflowError.